# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'getBeta'

Tags: r

I am trying to get Beta files using the minfi packacge. I succeeded with almost all my datasets. Therefor I ran the following code:

```
# find idat files
test_data <- list.files(path = "./Idat Files",
                        pattern = "_Grn.idat", 
                        full.names = TRUE)

# load data
test_data <- minfi::read.metharray(basenames = test_data) %>% 
  preprocessNoob %>% 
  getBeta
```

Problem #1: Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'getBeta': cannot load annotation package IlluminaHumanMethylationEPICanno.ilm10b4.hg19
```

Problem #2: Calling Beta values from another data set, using the same code as above, gave me another error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'getBeta': [read.metharray] Trying to parse IDAT files with different array size but seemingly all of the same type.
  You can force this by 'force=TRUE', see the man page ?read.metharray
```

Question: Does someone know what is going wrong?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] IlluminaHumanMethylationEPICmanifest_0.3.0         forcats_0.5.1                                     
 [3] stringr_1.4.0                                      dplyr_1.0.8                                       
 [5] purrr_0.3.4                                        readr_2.1.2                                       
 [7] tidyr_1.2.0                                        tibble_3.1.6                                      
 [9] ggplot2_3.3.5                                      tidyverse_1.3.1                                   
[11] minfiData_0.40.0                                   IlluminaHumanMethylation450kanno.ilmn12.hg19_0.6.0
[13] IlluminaHumanMethylation450kmanifest_0.4.0         RFpurify_0.1.2                                    
[15] minfi_1.40.0                                       bumphunter_1.36.0                                 
[17] locfit_1.5-9.5                                     iterators_1.0.14                                  
[19] foreach_1.5.2                                      Biostrings_2.62.0                                 
[21] XVector_0.34.0                                     SummarizedExperiment_1.24.0                       
[23] Biobase_2.54.0                                     MatrixGenerics_1.6.0                              
[25] matrixStats_0.61.0                                 GenomicRanges_1.46.1                              
[27] GenomeInfoDb_1.30.1                                IRanges_2.28.0                                    
[29] S4Vectors_0.32.4                                   BiocGenerics_0.40.0                               

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] readxl_1.4.0              backports_1.4.1           BiocFileCache_2.2.1       plyr_1.8.7               
  [5] splines_4.1.3             BiocParallel_1.28.3       digest_0.6.29             htmltools_0.5.2          
  [9] fansi_1.0.3               magrittr_2.0.3            memoise_2.0.1             tzdb_0.3.0               
 [13] limma_3.50.3              annotate_1.72.0           modelr_0.1.8              askpass_1.1              
 [17] siggenes_1.68.0           prettyunits_1.1.1         colorspace_2.0-3          rvest_1.0.2              
 [21] blob_1.2.3                rappdirs_0.3.3            haven_2.4.3               xfun_0.30                
 [25] jsonlite_1.8.0            crayon_1.5.1              RCurl_1.98-1.6            genefilter_1.76.0        
 [29] GEOquery_2.62.2           survival_3.2-13           glue_1.6.2                gtable_0.3.0             
 [33] zlibbioc_1.40.0           DelayedArray_0.20.0       Rhdf5lib_1.16.0           HDF5Array_1.22.1         
 [37] scales_1.2.0              DBI_1.1.2                 rngtools_1.5.2            Rcpp_1.0.8.3             
 [41] xtable_1.8-4              progress_1.2.2            bit_4.0.4                 mclust_5.4.9             
 [45] preprocessCore_1.56.0     httr_1.4.2                RColorBrewer_1.1-3        ellipsis_0.3.2           
 [49] farver_2.1.0              pkgconfig_2.0.3           reshape_0.8.9             XML_3.99-0.9             
 [53] dbplyr_2.1.1              utf8_1.2.2                labeling_0.4.2            tidyselect_1.1.2         
 [57] rlang_1.0.2               AnnotationDbi_1.56.2      cellranger_1.1.0          munsell_0.5.0            
 [61] tools_4.1.3               cachem_1.0.6              cli_3.2.0                 generics_0.1.2           
 [65] RSQLite_2.2.12            broom_0.8.0               evaluate_0.15             fastmap_1.1.0            
 [69] yaml_2.3.5                fs_1.5.2                  knitr_1.38                bit64_4.0.5              
 [73] beanplot_1.3.1            scrime_1.3.5              randomForest_4.7-1        KEGGREST_1.34.0          
 [77] nlme_3.1-155              doRNG_1.8.2               sparseMatrixStats_1.6.0   nor1mix_1.3-0            
 [81] xml2_1.3.3                biomaRt_2.50.3            compiler_4.1.3            rstudioapi_0.13          
 [85] filelock_1.0.2            curl_4.3.2                png_0.1-7                 reprex_2.0.1             
 [89] stringi_1.7.6             GenomicFeatures_1.46.5    lattice_0.20-45           Matrix_1.4-0             
 [93] multtest_2.50.0           vctrs_0.4.0               pillar_1.7.0              lifecycle_1.0.1          
 [97] rhdf5filters_1.6.0        data.table_1.14.2         bitops_1.0-7              rtracklayer_1.54.0       
[101] R6_2.5.1                  BiocIO_1.4.0              codetools_0.2-18          MASS_7.3-55              
[105] assertthat_0.2.1          rhdf5_2.38.1              openssl_2.0.0             rjson_0.2.21             
[109] withr_2.5.0               GenomicAlignments_1.30.0  Rsamtools_2.10.0          GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.7   
[113] hms_1.1.1                 quadprog_1.5-8            grid_4.1.3                base64_2.0               
[117] rmarkdown_2.13            DelayedMatrixStats_1.16.0 illuminaio_0.36.0         lubridate_1.8.0
```

Comment: To call a function, you always need parenthesis : `test_data <- minfi::read.metharray(basenames = test_data) %>% 
  preprocessNoob() %>% 
  getBeta()`